# Laravel: Use two Requests at the same time in a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have a function in my controller. The problem is I must use two Requests at the same time but only one of them can be used in a controller.

- Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request
- Illuminate\Http\Request

Code:

```
public function func(Request $req) {
    if (Request::isMethod('post')) {
        $this->validate($req, [
            'username' => 'required|string'
        ]);
    }
}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "request". Do you mean you want to use both *types*, you need two instances or you actually mean you want to process two (2) http requests at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to use both of them, you can alias them as below:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request as RequestNew;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as RequestOld;
```

And then you can reference the alias in your code.

eg: `RequestNew::isMethod('post')`

Comment: See using aliases in namespaces: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php